# Custom Component on Windows Forms not loading correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am new to Windows Forms and am trying to create a custom Panel which has a header bar with two labels. I want to be able to set the text of those labels from the designer when this panel is added to another form.

Here is the code for my Panel:

```
    public partial class TitledPanel : Panel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";
        public string TitleNumber
        {
            get { return numberedLabel.Text; }
            set { numberedLabel.Text = value; }
        }

        public TitledPanel()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
                new Pen(Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(229)))), ((int)(((byte)(229)))), ((int)(((byte)(229)))))), 0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.titleLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.mainHeaderPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.numberedLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.mainHeaderPanel.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // titleLabel
            // 
            this.titleLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.titleLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ((byte)(0)));
            this.titleLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(75, 27);
            this.titleLabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(32,32,32,32);
            this.titleLabel.Name = "titleLabel";
            this.titleLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(193, 30);
            this.titleLabel.TabIndex = 2;
            this.titleLabel.Text = "";
            // 
            // mainHeaderPanel
            // 
            this.mainHeaderPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(229)))), ((int)(((byte)(229)))), ((int)(((byte)(229)))));
            this.mainHeaderPanel.Controls.Add(this.numberedLabel);
            this.mainHeaderPanel.Controls.Add(this.titleLabel);
            this.mainHeaderPanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.mainHeaderPanel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.mainHeaderPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(64, 140);
            this.mainHeaderPanel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(64, 140, 64, 0);
            this.mainHeaderPanel.Name = "mainHeaderPanel";
            this.mainHeaderPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1126, 80);
            this.mainHeaderPanel.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // numberedLabel
            // 
            this.numberedLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.numberedLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(4)))), ((int)(((byte)(103)))), ((int)(((byte)(198)))));
            this.numberedLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 28F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ((byte)(0)));
            this.numberedLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.numberedLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 26);
            this.numberedLabel.Name = "numberedLabel";
            this.numberedLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(31, 32);
            this.numberedLabel.TabIndex = 3;
            this.numberedLabel.Text = "0";

            var path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
            path.AddEllipse(-1, 0, numberedLabel.Width, numberedLabel.Height);
            this.numberedLabel.Region = new Region(path);
            // 
            // TitledPanel
            // 
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Controls.Add(this.mainHeaderPanel);
            this.Name = "BeforeYouStartForm";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1254, 839);
            this.Text = "GetStarted";
            this.mainHeaderPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.mainHeaderPanel.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label titleLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel mainHeaderPanel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label numberedLabel;
    }
```

When I put this panel on a form and run the app, it looks like it should. However the fields `Title` and `TitleNumber` show up in the designer with the text `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` next to them. Also the panel does not load in the designer, when I add it to a form, it looks like the default Panel would, and it only loads when I actually run the app.

How can I get the TitledPanel to load in the designer and how can I get `Title` and `TitleNumber` to show correctly in the designer.

Thanks

Comment: Many mistakes here: the Region is set in the wrong place, it's defined once (so it never resizes when the text changes), also Regions don't support anti-aliasing, so the result is going to be terrible. Paint the background of the text instead. -- `Title` (a Property, not a Field) is never used. -- Painting the background with the `BackGround` Color value is useless, that's already done when `OnPaintBackGround()` is called -- Use `ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer` -- All in all, it looks like you want a User Control instead of a Custom Control -- I could not replicate the issue you described

Comment: BTW, the Pen is also a disposable object, not just the Brush. -- With *Paint the background of the text instead* I mean, ditch the Region and `Invalidate()` the Control when the Text changes, get the Bounds of the Control that shows the Text, inflate it by, say, 2 pixels and draw the ellipse around it, so you have anti-aliasing.

Comment: Or draw the text and the *contour* yourself, also ditching the Label.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the tips, but the real problem im facing is it not showing in the designer and the TitleNumber not being able to be set from designer - I know Title isnt doing anything right now, I originally had it the same as TitleNumber but it wasnt working so I tried something else but had the same result... any idea how to fix those issues?

Comment: Well, I copied the code you posted here, built a class from it, dropped the Control on a Form and the text of an exception is not there. The `TitleNumber` Property sets the Label's Text both at design-time and run-time (which is expected).

Comment: @Jimi huh... Wonder if somehow the way I set up my class caused it to break... how did you create the file? Just create a C# class and paste the code in?

Comment: @Jimi Okay so actually, I removed the component from my form, and re-added it, and it worked - I guess the component doesn't reload once changes are made and I had to delete and re-add it

Comment: Yes, as usual. Just added `using System.Windows.Forms;` and `using System.Drawing;,` compiled, got the Control from the ToolBox and dropped it on a Form. -- Note that when you make relevant changes to a Custom Control (while building an UserControl, VS warns you about it), you have to re-compile, but often you have to remove the Control from the hosting Form and drop a new instance, otherwise some parts already serialized (hence already in the `InitializeComponent()` method of the Form) may not work as intended (you have to suppose it won't work if you add / remove / redefine Properties etc.)